# Html table style first row with foreach

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, html-table

I have looked everywhere but couldn't find the right answer.

How can you style a html table, but only the first row. (And if possible als only the first column of the same row)

But now comes the tricky part, I use a foreach with a desc on it. So I retrieve the data from the database and not just have the data already in my table.

Here is what my code looks like:

```
<table class="table sortable" id="voteResults" name="voteResults">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Keuze</th>
      <th>Aantal punten</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  @foreach($lists as $i => $list)
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>{{ $list->option }}</td>
        <td>{{ $list->points }}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  @endforeach
</table>
```

But how can I style only the first column? And if possible give an image or border-color with it. (Basicly every css

I have updated my code a little bit ($i =>), with this, you can easily get the first id of the column. Only the next problem is, I don't know how to style it with an if function.. (if $i === 1 give background-color: red, for example)

Comment: What's this syntax: `@foreach`

Comment: This is the query: `$lists = DB::table('options')->orderBy('points', 'desc')->get();`

Comment: You don't understand. I am asking if this is PHP...

Comment: Anyway, check out my answer.

Comment: Oh sorry, it's a php function in laravel. Foreach row that he can find from the database he puts it in the table.

Comment: Guessed it would be laravel. Okay, check my answer and tell if it works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A CSS-only solution:

```
.table tbody:nth-child(2) tr:first-child td:first-child {
  border: 1px solid #cc0000;
}
```

selects the first row inside the body, then the first td inside that row.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Afirst-child

Comment: Thanks for your comment but this gives the same output as all the other ones that I found, it affects the whole column and not one row.

Comment: what browser are you using? Can you try this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/doc_snyder/efLmcd2r/ - for me it renders a red border only around the first cell in the first row.

Comment: Yes that's right, but you don't use a foreach, try it on your own with a fres project, some data in your database and a foreach to get the data and show it in your table. You will see that the whole first column get a round border and not only one row. By the way, I'm using chrome.

Comment: ah but why are you creating multiple tbody-elements? shouldn't you move the foreach inside the <tbody>?

Comment: nevertheless, i changed my answer to reflect your current html-structure. it now targets only the first tbody, too.

Comment: now I got it: i thought that the _tag_:first-child selector would target the first child that is of the type _tag_, but it is in fact the _tag_ ONLY IF it is the first child. So in your case the correct selector would be tbody:nth-child(2). I have updated my answer and the jsfiddle, please check it.

Comment: Thanks mate that did the trick! I have moved my foreach inside the `<tbody>` and gave this css code to it `.table tr:first-child td:first-child { border: 1px solid red; }`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply wrap it with a `<div />` or give a class `first` to it:

```
<td class="first">{{ $list->option }}</td>
```

And in CSS:

```
.first {padding-left: 50px; background: url("50px-image.png") left top no-repeat;}
```

In pure PHP, I would do:

```
  $first = true;
  @foreach($lists as $list)
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td{{ ($first) ? ' class="first"' : "" }}>{{ $list->option }}</td>
        <td>{{ $list->points }}</td>
        {{ $first = false }}
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  @endforeach
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but now he takes all the first td's op the first column, I only want that he takes the first row.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't worked, larael will output the `$first = true` as a '1' on my screen. But I have updated my code, Think I am very close now!